# Suspicious HEAD http requests

Tags: http, proxy, windows-10

On my Windows 10 machine, I run [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) on localhost:8080. I've changed the system proxy setting to point to my local proxy server.

Apart from what I expect to see, I can also see the following HEAD requests:

[image]

Typically, the headers look like this:

[image]

It looks the same for every request, just the Host header changes.

**What are these?** I tried to google the most of them, but I'm unable to get any relevant results.

In mitmproxy in event log, I can see records related to these requests (these 4 lines are related to the first `http://ewxfuvvehmlzvfd/` request):

```
127.0.0.1:55607: error establishing server connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
127.0.0.1:55607: client disconnect
127.0.0.1:55607: closing transports...
127.0.0.1:55607: transports closed!
```

I also tried to run:

```
> Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 55607).OwningProcess
```

with no useful result but `Get-NetTCPConnection : No MSFT_NetTCPConnection objects found with property 'LocalPort' equal to '55607'...`

Comment: Are you running Chrome?

Comment: I was running Brave, which is based on Chromium. Thank you for the link, that might be it.

Comment: I think it does. In that answer, there's also a link to https://serverfault.com/questions/235307/unusual-head-requests-to-nonsense-urls-from-chrome which explains it as well, perhaps in more detail, so I understand why Chrome, and it seems Brave based on Chromium as well, does it. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. That's what we're here for